# python MySQLdb - how to log warnings

Tags: python, logging, mysql-python

MySQLdb is really nice library for handling SQL connections. I found only one problem. It writes all warning messages directly to stdout. Is there any possibility to redirect it to standard python logger instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace [`warnings.showwarning()`](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#warnings.showwarning) with a function that works as desired.